# code works,but pydev show 'Undefined variable from import: ',and completion doesn't work

Tags: opencv, pydev, contour

OpenCV and Opencv-Contrib are built in my laptop,and blow code runs well,but as you can see,pydev shows a error:'Undefined variable from import: Tracker_create',and code completion doesn't work also,why?
[image]

Comment: You need OpenCV 3.2 complied with opencv_contrib. You are probably missing the opencv_contrib module

Comment: @RickM.thanks,I have,the code runs well and I compiled opencv with EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=''/path/to/opencv_contrib/modules"

Comment: But what version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried putting `cv2` in the forced builtins?

See http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html (look for `Forced Builtins` in that page for more details on why this may be needed).